# python - replace values in dataframe using another dataframe with same index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with missing values for some columns:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(data = {"name":['bob','sue','dave'],'status':[np.NaN,np.NaN,'A'],'team':['red','blue',np.NaN]},index=[100,101,105])
```

Dataframe `a`

[image: dataframe a]

I have another dataframe with the same index where some of the missing values have been replaced:

```
b = pd.DataFrame(data = {"name":['bob','sue','dave'],'status':['I','O','A'],'team':['red','blue',np.NaN]},index=[100,101,105])
```

Dataframe `b`

[image: dataframe b]

Is there a way to map dataframe `b` to `a` so that the values for specific columns in `a` are replaced? There are lots of other rows in `a` that aren't in `b` so I only want to replace the rows that have the same index.

I tried this but it sets the values to `np.NaN`:

```
a['status'] = a['status'].map(b['status'])
a['team'] = a['team'].map(b['team'])
```

Dataframe `a` after mapping

[image: dataframe a after b has been mapped]

Comment: ``a.combine_first(b)`` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by using the slice operation. The index of the second dataframe is used to slice the first dataframe

You then assign the second dataframe.

```
a.loc[b.index] = b
```

Output:

```
     name status  team
100   bob      I   red
101   sue      O  blue
105  dave      A   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

All credit to @Sushanth

```
>>> a.combine_first(b)
     name status  team
100   bob      I   red
101   sue      O  blue
105  dave      A   NaN
```